# Do not want Appendix to appear as a chapter

Tags: appendices

I have the following outline for my thesis, and when I compile, Appendix appears as a Chapter. And I do not want it as a chapter, just Appendix will be good. Is there anything wrong with my thesis outline?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{report}
\setlength{\textwidth}{16cm}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0pt}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{3mm}
\setlength{\parindent}{0mm}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{images/}}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{enumerate}% http://ctan.org/pkg/enumerate
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{thm-restate}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{abstract}
\doublespacing
A Heron triangle is a triangle that …
\end{abstract}

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\newpage

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\onehalfspacing
\chapter{Introduction}
\input{chapters/Introduction}

\onehalfspacing
\chapter{Background and Methodology}
\input{chapters/chapter2}

\onehalfspacing
\chapter{Values of $\delta(\mu)$}
\input{chapters/chapter3}

\onehalfspacing
\chapter{Existence of a Suitable Pair}
\input{chapters/chapter4}

\onehalfspacing
\chapter{Title}
\input{chapters/chapter5}

\onehalfspacing
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{reference}

\singlespacing
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\chapter{Appendix}
\input{chapters/Appendix}

\end{document}
```

Also, I have a very very long set of \usepackage{}, is there a way I can place all this packages in a different Tex file and just re-call it on my thesis outline. I tried doing this but I guess something went wrong that it did not want to compile.

Comment: What about using `\chapter*{Appendix}`?

Comment: Comment aside: Don't load both `enumerate` and `enumitem`. The functionalities of enumerate are available with enumitem. `epsfig` is totally obsolete, and can be replaced with `graphicx`, which you load. Finally, `cleveref` should be loaded at the end, and for standard classes, it's better and simpler to set up the layout of the page with `geometry`.

Comment: @Bernard Thank you for your comments. I really appreciate it. I have been loading all possible packages that I thought I might be using, and then end up not using it. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Typical `\chapter` representations include a heading as well as the chapter title. As such, issuing

```
\appendix
\chapter{Appendix}
```

may seem awkward since the repetition of **Appendix** seems redundant:

[image]

Instead, consider using only

```
\chapter*{Appendix}
```

[image]

Note that this implies the following:

1. The appendix chapter will not appear in the ToC (this is the default). If you wish to include it, formatted the way other `chapter`s are formatting, then add

   ```
   \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Appendix}
   %\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\numberline{}Appendix}
   ```

   after `\chapter*{Appendix}`. The first option prints the appendix entry flush with the left margin. The second option (commented above) inserts the appropriate amount of horizontal space to line up with other *numbered* chapters in the ToC.
2. Sectioning won't be used, since their enumeration will be flawed as it they still incorporate `\thechapter`. In addition you may have to also execute

   ```
   \renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
   ```

   which strips the default `\thechapter.` prefix from the numbering.

Comment: Thank you. I was trying to fix the Appendix not appearing in my TOC when you replied this. Thanks for the explanation.